# How to override a private method in javascript?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, overriding, prototype

I'm trying to use javascript object inheritance where I override a "private" method in the base "class" (in other words, make it a protected method).

Is it possible? Here's my best attempt (which doesn't work)

```
function Vehicle(color) {
    this.color = color;
}

Vehicle.prototype.drive = function() {
    _getMessage.call(this);
}

function _getMessage() {
    console.log("override this method!")
}


//----------------------------------------------------------------

var Car = (function() {

    Car.prototype = Object.create(Vehicle.prototype);
    Car.prototype.constructor = Car;

    function Car(color) {
        Vehicle.call(this, color)
    }

    function _getMessage() {
        console.log("The " + this.color + " car is moving!")
    }


    return Car;
}());

//----------------------------------------------------------------

$(function() {
    var c = new Car('blue');
    c.drive()

})
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/ZMB9izK1W9VuFQHPNsvu?p=preview

Comment: You can't this way. Also, the original `_getMessage` function is not actually part of your class.

Comment: `Here's my best attempt (which doesn't work)` - what's wrong with it? What do you expect? What do you get instead?

Comment: *_getMessage* is global, it's not "private" in any way, just replace it. If it actually was private, you can replace it if you have a privileged function specifically to do that.

Comment: `_getMessage` in your `Car` object is "private" in the sense that it is only visible in the scope of that IIFE ... and no amount of prototypal trickery or the newer `class` sugary goodness is going to make that function available outside that scope unless you make it available, therefore making it not "private"

Comment: @JaromandaX—but the "private" *_getMessage* is never called… so what's the point? ;-)

Comment: @RobG - I know that, I'm just suggesting that the concept is impossible anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could introduce a privileged method that can change the private one:

```js
// IIFE to create constructor
var Car = (function(){

  // Private method
  function _getMessage(text){
    console.log('original: ' + text);
  }

  // Normal constructor stuff
  function Car(make){
    this.make = make;
  }
  Car.prototype.getMake = function(){
    return this.make;
  }
  Car.prototype.getMessage = function(){
    _getMessage(this.make);
  }

  // Privileged function to access & change private method
  Car.changeGetMessage = function(fn) {
    _getMessage = fn;
  }
  return Car;
}());

// Demonstration
// Create instance
var ford = new Car('Ford');
console.log(ford.getMake());

// Call original method
ford.getMessage();

// Replace original
Car.changeGetMessage(function(text){
  console.log('new message: ' + text);
});

// Existing instances get new method
ford.getMessage();

// Create new instance
var volvo = new Car('Volvo');
console.log(volvo.getMake());

// New instances get method too
volvo.getMessage();
```